# How do I set up a different power shell command for different versions of python?

Tags: python, powershell

I'm currently learning Python and have run in to a minor inconvenience that seems like it should be easy to solve but after a couple hours of effort I haven't found anything specific and haven't been able to figure it out myself.

The tutorial I'm going through now uses python 2.7 but I have 2.7 and 3.5 installed so when I use the 'python' command in power shell ie. (python ex75.py) it tries to run the script using python 3.5 instead of python 2.7.

I'd really like to be able to use either version from the power shell command line.

Can I set it up so that I can use 'python27' to run scripts in python 2.7 and 'python35' to run scripts in python 3.5?

That's how the server I've playing around on works, different commands for python 2 and python 3 so I can use either from the command line but it's running ubuntu and I can't remember how I set it up anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell, enter the following:

```
$Env:PY_PYTHON = 2
```

Then try using the command "py". It should start up Python 2.7. If you ever want to run Python 3.5 again, "`py -3`" will do the trick.

Comment: @JosephWilson Please approve the answer as the correct answer then. Thanks!